# How can I make a row of relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

I am struggling with this for a while now, but I can't figure it out how it works.
In laravel I have a few models with relationships. I wan't to have al the accounts based on the logged in user and the passed parameter for the workspace.

This is how the models looks like: (I only coppied the methods to keep it short)

**The user Model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function workspaces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Workspace', 'user_id');
    }

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('account', 'Workspace', 'id', 'workspace_id');
    }
}
```

**The workspace model:**

```
class Workspace extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('account', 'workspace_id', 'id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**The account model**

```
class account extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function account_url()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('acountUrl', 'id', 'account_url_id');
    }
    public function workspace()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Workspace', 'workspace_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**The account_url model**

```
class account_url extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('account', 'id', 'account_url_id');
    }
}
```

So I want from the logged-in user with a specific workspace all the account with the account_urls
something like this: user->workspace->account->account_url

I tried the following things but it don't work:

```
$account_urls = user::find( Auth::user()->id)->first()->workspaces()->where('id', '=', 1)->account()->account_url()->select('url')->get();
```

and:

```
$account_urls = account::where('workspace_id', '=', '1')->account_url()->select('url')->get();
```

Only when I do it like this:

```
$account_urls = account::find(1)->account_url()->select('url')->get();
```

But then I get only 1 url, but when I replase find(1) for all() I get an error?

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Tanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relations are wrong, change them to:

```
// User
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Account', 'Workspace', 'user_id', 'workspace_id');
}

// Account
// use camelCase for relations
public function accountUrl()
{
    // I assume you have account_url_id on accounts table
    // If it's opposite, then use hasOne
    return $this->belongsTo('AcountUrl', 'account_url_id', 'id');
}

// AccountUrl (use camelCase)
public function account()
{
    // if above is hasOne, then here belongsTo instead.
    return $this->hasOne('account', 'account_url_id', 'id');
}
```

Now, fetching models:

```
// this part is .. amazing ;)
user::find( Auth::user()->id )->first();

// it does this:
Auth::user()->id // fetch user and get his id
user::find( .. ) // fetch user with given id, you have this user already above...
->first() // fetch first row from users table (not the one with id provided before)
```

so you want:

```
$account_urls = Auth::user()->workspaces()
   ->where('id', '=', 1)->first() // first fetches the result
   // or simply
   // ->find(1)
   ->accounts()->first()->accountUrl()
   ->pluck('url'); // this does 'SELECT url' and returns only this field instead of model
```

Just remember that:

```
$user->workspaces
$workspace->accounts
```

these are collections, so you can't call anything of the model on them, you need to get single model first.

Comment: tnx for your replay, I almost get it,
Your code works, but now i get only 1 url because I get the first workspace. But is is possible that I have multiple account in one workspace. How should I do that?

I thought I should replace the first() into all(), but then I got an error?

Comment: You can't get all the `accountUrl`s like that, because it's a collection of `Accounts`. Instead of `first` goes `get` and it will return the collection, then use `foreach` for example and get the urls one by one. And read the docs, they are pretty much all you need..

Comment: Ok tnx for your help!